# gcloud components update "readerror"

Tags: gcloud

This is my first post so sorry ahead of time for posting issues.
I need help with what it can't read.
Alternatively what gcloud version(s) do I need to get to 356.0.0.

Thanks

Details:

Your current Cloud SDK version is: 114.0.0
You will be upgraded to version: 356.0.0

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                      These components will be updated.                      │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┤
│                         Name                        │  Version   │   Size   │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ BigQuery Command Line Tool                          │     2.0.71 │  < 1 MiB │
│ BigQuery Command Line Tool (Platform Specific)      │     2.0.69 │  < 1 MiB │
│ Cloud SDK Core Libraries                            │ 2021.09.03 │ 20.1 MiB │
│ Cloud SDK Core Libraries (Platform Specific)        │ 2021.06.18 │  < 1 MiB │
│ Cloud Storage Command Line Tool                     │       4.67 │  4.3 MiB │
│ Cloud Storage Command Line Tool (Platform Specific) │       4.63 │  < 1 MiB │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│       These components will be installed.       │
├─────────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┤
│           Name          │  Version   │   Size   │
├─────────────────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ gcloud cli dependencies │ 2021.08.20 │ 11.0 MiB │
│ gcloud cli dependencies │ 2021.04.16 │  < 1 MiB │
└─────────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┘

A lot has changed since your last upgrade.  For the latest full release notes,
please visit:
 https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Creating update staging area                             ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Uninstalling: BigQuery Command Line Tool                 ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Uninstalling: BigQuery Command Line Tool (Platform Sp... ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Uninstalling: Cloud SDK Core Libraries                   ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Uninstalling: Cloud SDK Core Libraries (Platform Spec... ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Uninstalling: Cloud Storage Command Line Tool            ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Uninstalling: Cloud Storage Command Line Tool (Platfo... ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: BigQuery Command Line Tool                   ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: BigQuery Command Line Tool (Platform Spec... ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: Cloud SDK Core Libraries                     ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: Cloud SDK Core Libraries (Platform Specific) ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: Cloud Storage Command Line Tool              ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: Cloud Storage Command Line Tool (Platform... ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: gcloud cli dependencies                      ═╣
ERROR: gcloud crashed (ReadError): file could not be opened successfully

Comment: Try uninstalling the old version first. Reboot the system. Also, make sure you have the correct privilege (administrator / root).